How is the default nice value of a user's processes implemented in Ubuntu server 22.04.4 LTS
I've noticed that all services and processes with my user in Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 LTS have a nice value of 19. I connect to the server through ssh, and my ssh sessions also have a nice value of 19. I didn't use the nice or renice commands.
I'm searching for the configuration that produces this default nice value. So far, I've seen that /etc/security/limits.conf is the place to configure default nice value, but my current file is all commented out. Also I cannot find any reference to this nice value in the generic systemd user@.service or user.slice unit files.
In desktop Ubuntu, the default nice value is 0, so I assume it must be configurable.
Could you point me to the configuration file where this nice value of 19 is configured?

This is not enabled by default in any of known official Ubuntu releases.
You could inspect the output of sudo grep -E -i -w -r '19|20|nice' /etc.
20 is necessary because it's how renice/nice often used.
